# Logstash Removed from cluster after joining with elasticsearch in docker

Tags: docker, logstash

I am using docker to host my logstash and elasticsearch.
Logstash joins the cluster and then it disconnect after 2 sec's.
Below is the exception i am getting.

> [2015-08-31 23:30:40,880][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Ms.
>   MODOK] removed
>   {[logstash-da1b6e0a073b-1-11622][G_hYr0mcTZ6G-IOia1g5Cg][da1b6e0a073b][inet[/172.17.5.146:9300]]{data=false,
>   client=true},}, reason:
>   zen-disco-node_failed([logstash-da1b6e0a073b-1-11622][G_hYr0mcTZ6G-IOia1g5Cg][da1b6e0a073b][inet[/172.17.5.146:9300]]{data=false,
>   client=true}), reason transport disconnected

My logstash configuration file.

```
    input {
  stdin { }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
    host => elasticsearch 
    }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed it.
Need to add log file location, created volumes in docker and pointed input of logstash and everything started working.

```
file {
    path =>  [ "/opt/logs/test_log.json" ]
    codec =>   json {
      charset => "UTF-8"
    }
  }
```